# Design guidelines for converting from ClassA to ClassB

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I just began work on a large c# code base. Several classes in the code are almost identical to others, which is a question in and of itself, and need to be converted in order to reuse existing logic.

Currently in the code there are extention methods scattered around which take a bit of effort to find and figure out what they are called in order to use them. I would like to move all the convert methods into the class so that they could very easily be found and used. However, I am not sure what is the most accepted way of converting one data type to another when you have the source for everything.

In order to convert ClassA to ClassB should I:

1. add a method to ClassA,
2. create a ClassAHelper,
3. use an extention method for ClassA?

Comment: Could you provide an example of 2 of these classes? I suspect you could extract a base class from the ones that have a lot in common, and have them all inherit from the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code to convert one class to another (I assume you're talking about runtime conversions) may not be the necessary way to go. For example, if you have class X and class Y that each have `void Blah()` that you wish to invoke from method C, and method C takes X as a parameter, what you might instead do is extract a common interface for X and Y and then have C accept the interface instead. Therefore your Y can remain Y.

Another option is to use the **adapter pattern** which can make Y conform to the extracted interface of X, and this is particularly useful if Y has the same general functionality but under a different name, or if changing the code of one of the classes is painful, impossible, or simply undesired.

An example, given

```
interface ICanBlah { void Blah(); }
class X : ICanBlah { public void Blah() { } }
class Y { public void Blahhhhh() { } }
```

You can write

```
public class YBlahAdapter : ICanBlah 
{
    Y itsY;

    public YBlahAdapter(Y y) { itsY = y; }
    public void Blah() { itsY.Blahhhhh(); }
}
```

So wherever you have a method that takes `ICanBlah` and you have an object of type `Y`, you can wrap it in an adapter and then pass the adapter to the method.

On the other hand, if you really want to do a runtime conversion of X to Y or Y to X, you can define implicit or explicit conversion operators for one or both.

```
public static explicit operator Y(X x) { /* build and return Y from X */ }
```

(This operator would need to be declared in the source file of one of the types.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try yet another option:

Create a constructor function for ClassB that takes a ClassA object.

Then you could do:

```
ClassA foo = new ClassA();
ClassB bar = new ClassB(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't one in your list of answers but if everything is the same exept for one or two methods. Then I would look at making ClassB inherit ClassA and delete the common methods. This is assuming they are in the same family...